# Answers referencing other answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes answers start out like:

> In addition to what [other person] said ...

Is it valid to add additional information to other answers like this? Should the poster repeat what is in the other answer so that the one answer stands as a whole?

This is mostly done when the additional information is more than just an extra fact.

In general people want to be respectful to the other answerer, but it makes choosing the correct answer difficult.

Comment: As long as it's "in addition to what [name]" said and not "in addition to the answer [above/below]", it seems fine to me. (The latter breaks when/if answers change order due to voting.)

Comment: In addition to [what @abbyhairboat said](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255/answers-referencing-other-answers?cb=1#comment530_255), I highly recommend linking directly to the referenced answer/comment (and editing others' posts to do so, where there is no uncertainty about which post is referenced) in case the user's display name changes or the answer/comment is deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a problem here.  This is assuming some additional information relevant (doesn't even need to be directly answering) to the question is actually given.

There can be a fine line here between what is appropriate for a comment to the other answer versus a new answer of its own, but if it supplies new relevant information to the question then go ahead and make it a answer.